# the run time aborting when calling c++ sub from fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, mixing

I had read many posts here about mixing languages use of Fortran and C++. However, I'm still stuck with my current problem: my Fortran program always aborted.

---

I have the Fortran program: test-cc.f90 and the C++ program: deb_cc.cc.

deb_cc.cc contains:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void deb_cc_(float*** rh,int* x, int* y , int* z_ext )
{
  cout <<"thinkdeb 1"<<endl;
  int i, j, k;
  cout <<"thinkdeb 1"<<endl;
  cout <<"thinktest i=8,j=4,k=1"<< " (*x) " << (*x)<<endl;
  cout <<"thinktest i=8,j=4,k=1"<< " x3/rh " << rh[1][1][1]<<endl; //abortion                        
                                                                //      here 
  cout <<"thinkdeb 7"<<endl;
  return;
}//end function
```

test-cc.f90 contains:

```
    use ISO_C_BINDING

    implicit none

    interface
      subroutine  deb_cc( rh,x,y,z_ext)
        use ISO_C_BINDING
        implicit none
        real(c_float),allocatable::rh(:,:,:)
        integer(c_int):: x,y,z_ext
      end subroutine
    end interface

    integer nx,ny,nz
    parameter (nx=10,ny=10,nz=10)
    real  ,dimension (:,:,:),allocatable:: x1
    integer:: iy1,iy2,iy3,iy4
    integer i,j,k

    allocate(x1(nx,ny,nz))

    do k=1,nz
      do j=1,ny
        do i=1,nx
          x1(i,j,k)=k*1000+j*100+i
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo

    iy1=nx
    iy2=ny
    iy3=nz

    call deb_cc(x1,iy1,iy2,iy3)

  end
```

I compiled them by `pgf90 -c test-cc.f90` and `pgcpp -c deb_cc.cc`
Finally, I linked them by `pgf90 -pgcpplibs  test-cc.o  deb_cc.o`. 
The output is:

```
 thinktest in test- x1 (8,2,2) is     2208.000
 thinkdeb 1
 thinkdeb 1
 thinktest i=8,j=4,k=1 (*x) 10
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This isn't related to the problem (as given in the answer below), but the arguments to the call to `deb_cc` are default real/integer rather than explicitly the C-interoperable kinds.  The kinds are the same (or the compiler would complain) but for maximum portability consider declaring the variables with those interoperable kinds.  Note also that the first `use iso_c_binding` has no effect because of this.

Comment: Fracescalus, do you mean I should use the c_int and so on in the main fortran program? Thanks

Comment: It is what I would do, not just for those times where `real` is not the same as `real(c_float)` but for clarity.  Where they are the same, though, it isn't necessary (yet still doesn't hurt).

Comment: Got your point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the `iso_c_binding` module, but your procedure interface is not C interoperable.

**The `iso_c_binding` module is not the most important thing. The `bind(C)` attribute is the key.** (I ranted several times about the unfortunate name of the tag here)

You use an assumed shape allocatable array argument

```
real(c_float),allocatable::rh(:,:,:)
```

these are not allowed in interoperable procedures in Fortran 2008, because C or C++ have no idea what to do with them. They are not just addresses. If you used the `bind(C)` attribute in the interface, the compiler should tell you it is wrong.

There is a possibility to pass them in the next Fortran standard (in an existing TS actually) using a special C header, but some compilers (notably gfortran) are still not compatible.

As you do not do any reallocation on the C side (at least in your example), you can just pass the array as an assumed size (`array(*)`) argument. I also changed the C++ name, no need for the underscore.

```
interface
  subroutine  deb_cc(rh,x,y,z_ext) bind(C, name="deb_cc")
    use ISO_C_BINDING
    real(c_float) :: rh(*)
    integer(c_int):: x,y,z_ext
   end subroutine
end interface
```

On the C side, you cannot use the C arrays which are pointers to pointers ([i][j][k]). What you receive from Fortran is a single block of memory. You also have to pass the array shape. At least in the first two Fortan dimensions.

I would just use a macro to index the array in C.

```
// adjust as needed, many variants possible
#define IND(i,j,k) = i + (j-1) * nx + (k-1) * nx * ny
// adjust as needed, many variants possible


extern "C" void deb_cc(float *rh, int *nx, int *ny, int *nz) {
  cout <<"thinktest i=8,j=4,k=1"<< " x3/rh " << rh(IND(8,4,1))<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes. Modified the codes as you pointed out, it works now. However, for my actual goal, I need to use the pointers (rh in the c++ sub, defined with 3 *) in the form of 3d arrays. This is the way it is used in the original c++ codes.  Why it doesn't work now when It was called from the fortran? Did I miss something? Your futher clarificaiton is appreciated.

Comment: BTW: I'm sorry for the intendation problems.

Comment: Where are the arrays actually created, in C++ or in Fortran? These two forms can be incompatible. Fortran requires contiguous arrays to send them or receive them from C.

Comment: The actual array x1 was created in the fortran as an allocatable arrays. The arugument in c++ is defined as the ***rh (pointer to pointer to pointer). is that kind of pointers able to be used as the 3d arrays?

Comment: You have to set-up a sequence of pointers to the rows of the big array yourself inside C++, you can't pass that (easily) from Fortran. See `array2` in http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html

Comment: Vladimir, Thanks a lot. That is interesting. Seem such setup done in the c++ main (calling the sub) can be inherited while it won't work when the sub is called from fortran. Another important lesson to me. Thanks again.